# Probability Generating Function of $X^2$ in terms of $G_X(z)$.

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, random-variables, generating-functions

I am struggling with an infinite sum in the computation of the PGF of $X^2$ in terms of that of $X$. Suppose you define the random variable $Z=X^2$, where $X\in\mathbb{N}$. We know that $G_X(z)=\sum_{k\geq 0}z^kPr(X=k)$. Then, when I try to express $G_Z(z)$ in terms of $G_X(z)$, I use the fact that $X$ is always non-negative and takes values in $\mathbb{N}$. Namely
$$\begin{align}
G_Z(z)=\sum_{k\geq 0}z^kPr(Z=k)&=\sum_{k\geq 0}z^kPr(X=\pm\sqrt{k})\\
&=\sum_{k\geq 0}z^kPr(X=\sqrt{k})\\
&=\sum_{k\geq 0}z^{k^2}Pr(X=k),
\end{align}$$ but I am stuck in this last step and don't know how to get rid of the $z^{1/k}$ factor to obtain $G_X(z)$ again. Any help or advice is more than welcome.

Comment: I figured out that maybe we should approach the problem differently since this last sum is quite hectic to compute. I could only manage to upper bound this sum, but this wouldn't give me a PGF anyway, so...